# Do higher etale homotopy groups of spectrum of a field always vanish?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-covers

Let $k$ be a field. In what generality is it true that higher etale homotopy groups 
of $\mathrm{Spec}\,k$ vanish?

If the absolute Galois group is finite, we have a universal cover $\mathrm{Spec}\,k^{sep}\rightarrow\mathrm{Spec}\,k$ which, I believe, is the initial object of the category of etale hypercovers. If we apply $\pi_0$ to the simplicial $k$-scheme associated to this cover, the result coincides on the nose with the bar construction for the classifying space of $Gal(k^{sep}/k)$.

I am not sure what happens for general fields.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The étale topos of a field $k$ is just the topos of sets with a continuous $\mathrm{Gal}(k)$-action (here continuous is equivalent to all stabilizers being open), hence it is the colimit (in the ∞-category of topoi) of the topos of $\mathrm{Gal}(k)/H$-sets where $H$ ranges through the open subgroups of $\mathrm{Gal}(k)$.

Since the étale homotopy type commutes with (homotopy) colimits, we have that the étale homotopy type of $(\mathrm{Spec}\,k)_{ét}$ is the homotopy colimit of $B\mathrm{Gal}(k)/H$, and so it is the profinite space usually written $B\mathrm{Gal}(k)$ or $K(\mathrm{Gal}(k),1)$. In particular it has no higher homotopy groups.

Comment: No need for $\infty$-categories here :-)

Comment: @DavidRoberts Well sure. But there's no need to avoid them either :). Also I'm not sure if the étale homotopy type commutes with strict colimit (what would they even be in the target?), so I erred on the safe side. I know you can avoid ∞-cats by arguing that it is a cofinal family of hypercovers, but I decided that it wasn't worth the contorsions

Comment: I mean: the technology to compute colimits in the 2-category of toposes has been around a lot longer than colimits in $\infty$-toposes (SGA4?), and easier to grasp and work with.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Let's agree to disagree on what's easier to grasp and work with :). No discussion about it being earlier though (I think in this case they are essentially equivalent, my throwing the $\infty$ there was mainly a little attempt to demistify the image of $\infty$-cats as something esoteric).

Comment: I'm an Australian, 2-categories are my bag. Ah, well, I hope your attempt works :-)

Comment: how to see that etale homotopy type commutes with homotopy colimits?

Comment: @schematic_boi It's the left adjoint of the functor sending every profinite space to the ∞-topos of local systems over it.

Comment: It is not the case that the homotopy type respects colimits in the 2-category of 1-topoi in general. It happens to be true for this example, but one has to give an ad hoc argument for that. So, on the contrary, the kind of argument Denis is giving is *precisely* where the ∞-categorical point of view has a nontrivial conceptual advantage.

Comment: Actually, you should use Cech overs, not hypercovers, otherwise what you say is only true up to protruncated completion. Hypersheaves on the small etale site of $k$ is not always the colimit you describe, but it is true for ordinary sheaves. See Warning 7.2.2.31 of HTT- it follows that the shape of the hypercompletion of classifying topos of the p-adic integers is not $B \mathbb{Z}_p,$ as these pro-spaces differ on any space all of whose homotopy groups are of $p$-torsion. In the old literature, people were always working up to "#"-equivalence, which is actually just protruncated completion.

Comment: @DavidCarchedi You're absolutely right and that's actually what I was doing. I shouldn't have used "hypercovers" in my first comment. Unfortunately it's way too late to edit it (I tend to be a bit careless because I usually use only the profinite shape anyway).